# NPM module "only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here." in Ionic 2 / Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, ionic2

I'm trying to import the npm module "ajv" into my Ionic 2 (Angular 2) project.  (https://epoberezkin.github.io/ajv/)

I ran "npm install ajv --save", then made the following changes to my app.modules.js file:

```
import { Ajv } from 'ajv';

...
providers : [
    Ajv,
    ...
]
```

When I compile, however, I get the error:

```
'Ajv' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
c:/Users/me/Documents/Ionic/MyApp/src/app/app.module.ts
```

Is there a better way to pull in this library?

Comment: You're right!   If you want to move your comment to the answer, I'll mark it as correct, along with notes.

Comment: I suppose that was indeed more of an answer than a comment. Posted and elaborated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The providers array in `NgModule` is for use with `@Injectable` components or similarly functional "providers" or "services" in other speak. This library does not appear to conform to that design.

It's likely that all you really want to do is use the import within your application component, rather than in `AppModule`. By import I mean the simple ES6 style `import` of "symbol" and then direct usage in code.

So for example in **example.component.ts**:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Ajv } from 'ajv';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css']
})
export class ExampleComponent {

  myMethod() {
     // Just use Ajv here
  }

}
```

No need to put this in the decorator arrays.

If an imported third party library is rather something you want to use in a "service like manner", then by all means wrap it as an `@Injectable` service, but the consumption will stay much the same as the the above example.

Comment: You're right.  To get it to work, I simply added "import Ajv from 'ajv';" to my provider.  From there I can do "var ajv = new Ajv();" wherever I like.  I'm not sure if there's a technical difference between "import Ajv from 'ajv';" and "import { Ajv } from 'ajv';".  According to https://ionicframework.com/docs/resources/third-party-libs/ there is, but I don't understand the difference.  Not using braces worked for me.   Thanks Neil!

Comment: @Anthony the difference is the "module" ( JavaScript not Angular ) either "exports" the symbols for use with `{ ... }` and/or do a "default" export. So the different syntax varies between the two. See the [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) documentation.